# Options to achieve consensus in an immutable distributed hash table

Tags: hashtable, distributed-computing, consensus

I'm implementing a completely decentralized database. Anyone at any moment can upload any type of data to it. One good solution that fits on this problem is an immutable distributed hash table. Values are keyed with their hash. Immutability ensures this map remains always valid, simplifies data integrity checking, and avoids synchronization.

To provide some data retrieval facilities a tag-based classification will be implemented. Any key (associated with a single unique value) can be tagged with arbitrary tag (an arbitrary sequence of bytes). To keep things simple I want to use same distributed hash table to store this tag-hash index.

To implement this database I need some way to maintain a decentralized consensus of what is the actual and valid tag-hash index. Immutability forces me to use some kind of linked data structure. How can I find the root? How to synchronize entry additions? How to make sure there is a single shared root for everybody?

Answer (score 0):

In a distributed hash table you can have the nodes structured in a ring, where each node in the ring knows about at least one other node in the ring (to keep it connected). To make the ring more fault-tolerant make sure that each node has knowledge about more than one other node in the ring, so that it is able to still connect if some node crashes. In DHT terminology, this is called a "sucessor list". When the nodes are structured in the ring with unique IDs and some stabilization-protocol, you can do key lookups by routing through the ring to find the node responsible for a certain key.

> How to synchronize entry additions?

If you don't want replication, a weak version of decentralized consensus is enough and that is that each node has its unique ID and that they know about the ring structure, this can be achieved by a periodic stabilization protocol, like in Chord: http://nms.lcs.mit.edu/papers/chord.pdf

The stabilization protocol has each node communicating with its successor periodically to see if it is the true successor in the ring or if a new node has joined in-between in the ring or the sucessor has crashed and the ring must be updated. Since no replication is used, to do consistent insertions it is enough that the ring is stable so that peers can route the insertion to the correct node that inserts it in its storage. Each item is only held by a single node in a DHT without replication.

This stabilization procedure can give you very good probability that the ring will always be stable and that you minimize inconsistency, but it cannot guarantee strong consistency, there might be gaps where the ring is temporary unstable when nodes joins or leaves. During the inconsistency periods, data loss, duplication, overwrites etc could happen.

If your application requires strong consistency, DHT is not the best architecture, it will be very complex to implement that kind of consistency in a DHT. First of all you'll need replication and you'll also need to add a lot of ACK and synchronity in the stabilization protocol, for instance using a 2PC protocol or paxos protocol for each insertion to ensure that each replica got the new value.

> How can I find the root?
>   How to make sure there is a single shared root for everybody?

Typically DHTs are associated with some lookup-service (centralized) that contains IPs/IDs of nodes and new nodes registers at the service. This service can then also ensure that each new node gets a unique ID. Since this service only manages IDs and simple lookups it is not under any high load or risk of crashing so it is "OK" to have it centralized without hurting fault-tolerance, but of course you could distribute the lookup service as well, and sycnhronizing them with a consensus protocol like Paxos.